# Surge.sh / Unable to update project

Tags: surge.sh

I am having an issue updating surge project.

After the initial project commit any new updates don't seem to work.

Tried updating the project several times, but seems that server still returns a version of first project upload.

Cache is not an issue, because the issue the same project version is served up across different devices.

Any advice, please?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It works normally after I `npm install -g surge`